# How to factorize $(x-2)^5+x-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

This is a difficult problem.
How to factorize this?

$$(x-2)^5+x-1$$

we can't do any thing now and we should expand it first:

$$x^5-10x^4+40x^3-80x^2+81x-33$$

but I can't factorize it.

Comment: What tools are you allowed to use to find roots of this polynomial?

Comment: what do you mean? we can use algebra. but I can't understand that symbol in Martin's answer.

Comment: This seems like a pretty difficult question for precalculus. What I was getting at was something like the Rational root theorem, or perhaps using a computer to figure out a few roots. So you have to do this by hand only with algebra?

Comment: I know it is hard. but yes. this question is designed to be solved with algebra.

Comment: @bluesky: It's a Greek letter, pronounced "dzeta", and commonly used for the [roots of unity](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), which you should read up on to understand the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the substitution $t=x-2$, it suffices to factor $t^5 + t+1$.

But $t^2+t+1$ divides $t^5+t+1$. Why?

$t^2+t+1 = (t-\zeta)(t-\zeta')$, where $\zeta,\zeta'$ are the primitive $3rd$ roots of unity, and thus $\zeta^5 + \zeta + 1 = \zeta^2 + \zeta + 1 = 0$, similarly for $\zeta'$.

Now, the quotient $(t^5+t+1)/(t^2+t+1)$ is easily determined via polynomial division.

*Alternative solution.* Using $t^3-1=(t^2+t+1)(t-1)$, we get:
$$t^5+t+1=(t^5-t^2)+(t^2+t+1)=(t^3-1)t^2 + (t^2+t+1)$$
$$=(t^2+t+1)(t-1)t^2 + (t^2+t+1) = (t^2+t+1)((t-1)t^2+1)$$

Comment: This is explained in the 3rd paragraph. To be honest, I first factored over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (bearing in mind that every factorization over $\mathbb{Z}$ induces one over every $\mathbb{F}_p$), and $t^2+t+1$ is the unique irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$. This is quite useful!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg. I seems your answer is complete and right but I understood non of your words except the substitution !

Comment: I've added an alternative solution (which is basically the same as, and in fact motivated by, my previous approach). Written that way, it is quite a mystery, but actually it is not.

Answer (score 2):

finally found how looking in my previous questions.

first substitute $n=x-2$ then

$$(x-2)^5+x-1=n^5+n+1$$

$$n^5+n+1=n^5-n^2+n^2+n+1=n^2(n^3-1)+n^2+n+1$$

$$=n^2(n-1)(n^2+n+1)+n^2+n+1$$

$$=(n^2+n+1)(n^3-n^2+1)$$

Comment: +1 but the choise of $n$ for the variable is rather strange :-)

Comment: If you look at my profile. I had a question " How to factorize $n^5+n+1$?"

Comment: Well and this equals my solution ..

Answer (score -2):

you can also use $$(x-2)^5 + x - 1 = (x-2)^5 + (x-2) + 1=(x-2+0.754)(x^4+\cdots) $$

$\bf edit:$  $0.754$ is the only real root of $t^5+t+1 = 0.$

Comment: Why is the last part so? Can you write the complete form?

Comment: -1, here's why: The polynomial has no rational roots. You have written down a rational approximation of a real root, without any explanation where it did come from. Also, it should be clear that the aim is a *rational* factorization.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, op made no such constraints.

Comment: I can't use the roots. and I don't know what they are! I should factorize it with basic algebra and formulas.